# ORA-01843 Not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I have seen most of the topics about this error but I can't seem to understand what people mean. But this is my codes:

```
create table vehicle
(
v_ID CHAR (10) not null,
v_Model VARCHAR2 (20) not null,
v_manufacterer VARCHAR2 (20) not null,
plate_number CHAR (10) not null,
arive_date DATE  not null,
pickup_date DATE not null
);
```

This is the table and it got dropped/created
I want to insert these values in the column but it keeps giving me the error, I looked at all the other solutions but that are a bit different than mine. It might be simple but, I'm new to SQL.

```
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_Date, pickup_Date) VALUES ('V100','BMW','430i','N-55530','01-02-2015','02-02-2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number. arive_Date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V102','Lexus','LS300','M-33833','11/05/2015','12/05/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V101',' Mercedes','E350','A-15553','23/04/2015','23/04/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V104','Nissan','Tiida','O-1885','31/09/2015','03/10/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V105','Renault','Duster','A-19994','15/04/2015','15/04/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V106','GMC','Denali','O-60635','22/02/2015','23/02/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V107','Ford','Explorer','N-51951','11/08/2015','11/08/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V108','Ford','Mustang','G-33099','28/11/2015','29/11/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V109','Jeep','Wrangler','O-99199','22/09/2015','24/09/2015');
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V110','Dodge','Charger','E-1370','14/04/2015','14/04/2015');
```

I tried changing the format to each possible option:

```
04/14/2015 or 2015/04/14 - 2015/14/04 or even Apr-14-2015.
```

None of them seem to work.

What I want is to insert the arrival date and pick up date of the following vehicles (belonging to customers)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Always be specific when you have dates formatted as text: do the conversion explicitly with the correct date/time format for your data.

```
to_date('14/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Do that for all date inputs.

Comment: INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V110','Dodge','Charger','E-1370',to_date('14/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')); 

If this is what I should do it gave me a new error, ORA-0094 - Not enough values

Comment: Well, that's because you're not passing enough values. How many dates in your insert clause? How many dates in your value list?

Comment: In total there is 20 dates for both pickup and arrive in each insert clause. 
by value list I'm not sure what you mean.

From V100-till V110 so 10 raws, and 2 dates in each.

Comment: You're doing `insert into foo(a,b,c) values (1,2)`.

Comment: The method you just taught me is for 1 value or two? Because in case it's 
to_date('14/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') for one value I should put it two times for the two dates in the insert clause.

Comment: What does it look like? How many dates are passed in to that function? How could a function expand to two dates? Please take some time to look into the documentation too.

Comment: Scratch that it worked as:
INSERT INTO vehicle (V_ID, V_Model, V_manufacterer, plate_number, arive_date, pickup_date) VALUES ('V110','Dodge','Charger','E-1370',TO_DATE ('14/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE ('15/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'));


Thanks a lot Mat ^^